# How can I make security groups have bidirectional dependency on each other?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm new to AWS and trying to learn how to create template for stack in CloudFormation.I have two security groups for the instance and for the database.

```
 "InstanceSecurityGroup": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
          "Properties": {
            "GroupDescription": "Enable tomcat, ssh, mysql access via port 8080, 22, 3306 as well",
            "SecurityGroupIngress": [
              {
                "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                "FromPort": 8080,
                "ToPort": 22,
                "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
              },
              {
                "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                "FromPort": 3306,
                "ToPort": 3306,
                "SourceSecurityGroupId": {"Ref":"DatabaseSecurityGroup"}
              },
              {
                "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                "FromPort": 22,
                "ToPort": 22,
                "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "DatabaseSecurityGroup": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
          "Properties": {
            "GroupDescription": "Enable mysql database access to instance and back via port 3306",
            "SecurityGroupIngress": [
              {
                "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                "FromPort": 3306,
                "ToPort": 3306,
                "SourceSecurityGroupId": {"Ref": "InstanceSecurityGroup"}
              }
            ]
          }
        }
```

Should I use "dependsOn" attribute or it below code gonna work? Should I use  "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress" insted "standard" SecurityGroup?

Comment: As a general rule, you can't use `dependsOn` to resolve mutually dependent resources. Assuming that you really need to do this with security groups (which is not typically the case, and is not the case here), you should be able to do this with `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your configuration is:

- An Amazon EC2 instance
- A database that should permit inbound access from the EC2 instance

For this, you would configure:

- `InstanceSecurityGroup` that permits Inbound access for SSH and "All Outbound" access
- `DatabaseSecurityGroup` that permits Inbound access on port 3306 from `InstanceSecurityGroup`

There is **no need to permit inbound access from the database to the EC2 instance**. Security Groups are *stateful*, meaning that return traffic is automatically permitted. The database will never *initiate* a connection to the EC2 instance, so an Inbound rule is not required.

Thus, you will not have two security groups referring to each other.